# Default category on create new from many2one

Tags: odoo, many-to-one, odoo-9

I created a many2one field to select a product in a form. I filter the possible items to choose with a domain:

```
light_system = fields.Many2one(
    'product.product',
    string='Lighting System',
    ondelete='restrict',
    domain=[('categ_id.name', '=','Lighting System')]
)
```

If I create a new item directly from this dropdown with "create new" the category is not set to 'lighting system' therefore it won't show up when I try to use it again, risking duplicates of the same item by different users...
Is it possible to get the category to be set to "Lighting System" by default when I choose to create a new item directly from this field with 'create new""' or 'create and edit""' ?

I tried

```
<field name="light_system"
       placeholder="Lighting System"
       context="{'default_categ_id':'Lighting System'}"/>
```

and

```
<field name="light_system"
       placeholder="Lighting System"
       context="{'default_categ_id.name':'Lighting System'}"/>
```

in the form view, but neither works

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the category id:

```
<field name="light_system"
   placeholder="Lighting System"
   context="{'default_categ_id':lighting_id}"/>
```

if you have it as field into the form, even hidden

If you created the category in a data.xml of some module, you can use ref:

```
<field name="light_system"
   placeholder="Lighting System"
   context="{'default_categ_id':ref('name_of_the_module.lighting_id')}"/>
```

Comment: That helped a lot, thanks... I got to the point of adding data in XML to be able to reference with `ref('module.record_id)` no errors on module update, but I'm getting a "NameError: name 'ref' is not defined" when using it.

Comment: I got it, I was trying to use it in a `<field name="context">{'default_categ_id':ref('name_of_the_module.lighting_id')}</field>` and that doesn't work, it can be done as `<field name="context" eval="{'default_categ_id':ref('name_of_the_module.lighting_id')}"/>`

Comment: Ok, I'm at a loss, I was able to use it as described in my comments above to filer a treeview, but I still cannot make it work in a <field> tag as described in your answer. It works fine with the hard coded id of the category, but I can't figure out how to pass the external id of the record created in the xml data file. `context="{'default_categ_id':ref('name_of_the_module.lighting_id')}` gives me a `Uncaught Error: NameError: name 'ref' is not defined`

Comment: that's strange. I did not use it this way, but I've seen it (see [code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/survey/wizard/survey_email_compose_message.xml) at row 22). Maybe it doesn't work only in views.

Comment: Strange indeed, I will play some more with it, but for now it looks like I have to keep the ID hard coded, less than Ideal if I ever want to reuse the module...